# spring-integration-kafka dispatcher has no subscriber kafka backed message channel

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-integration

I am trying to use a message channel backed by kafka,
The flow is as below:

http --> gateway --> kafka-in  --> kafka-transform --> kafka-out

My code is as below:

Controller:

```java
gateway.sendToKafka(KafkaConfig.KAFKA_OUTPUT_TOPIC, UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "Hello: " + now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
```

Gateway:

```
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "kafkaInput")
public interface KafkaGateway {
    @Gateway
    Message<?> sendToKafka(@Header(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC) String replyTopic,
                           @Header(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID) String correlationId,
                           String message);
}
```

Config

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Transformer;
import org.springframework.integration.kafka.channel.SubscribableKafkaChannel;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.requestreply.ReplyingKafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;

/**
 * Reference
 * <a href="https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations_on_beans">...</a>
 */

@Slf4j
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaConfig {
    private final ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> replyingKafkaTemplate;
    private final MessageChannel toSuccessChannel;
    private final MessageChannel toFailureChannel;

    public static final String KAFKA_INPUT_TOPIC = "kafka-in";
    public static final String KAFKA_TRANSFORM_TOPIC = "kafka-transform";
    public static final String KAFKA_OUTPUT_TOPIC = "kafka-out";


    @Bean
    public SubscribableKafkaChannel kafkaInput(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory) {
        final SubscribableKafkaChannel channel = new SubscribableKafkaChannel(replyingKafkaTemplate, factory, KAFKA_INPUT_TOPIC);
        channel.setGroupId("in-grp");
        return channel;
    }

    @Bean
    public SubscribableKafkaChannel toKafkaTransform(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory) {
        final SubscribableKafkaChannel channel = new SubscribableKafkaChannel(replyingKafkaTemplate, factory, KAFKA_TRANSFORM_TOPIC);
        channel.setGroupId("transform-grp");
        return channel;
    }

    @Bean
    public SubscribableKafkaChannel kafkaOutput(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory) {
        final SubscribableKafkaChannel channel = new SubscribableKafkaChannel(replyingKafkaTemplate, factory, KAFKA_OUTPUT_TOPIC);
        channel.setGroupId("out-grp");
        return channel;
    }


    @Transformer(inputChannel = "kafkaInput", outputChannel = "toKafkaTransform")
    public Message<?> fromKafkaChannelHandler(Message<?> input) {
        log.info("*****************transformer*******************");
        final String payload = (String) input.getPayload();
        log.info("header: {}", input.getHeaders());
        log.info("payload: {}", payload);
        log.info("*****************transformer*******************");
        return MessageBuilder.createMessage(payload + " \t => transformed!", input.getHeaders());
    }

    @Transformer(inputChannel = "toKafkaTransform", outputChannel = "kafkaOutput")
    public Message<?> fromTransformToOutput(Message<?> input) {
        log.info("*****************output*******************");
        final String payload = (String) input.getPayload();
        log.info("header: {}", input.getHeaders());
        log.info("payload: {}", payload);
        log.info("*****************output*******************");
        return MessageBuilder.createMessage(payload + "\t => transformed!" + "\t => dispatched", input.getHeaders());
    }


}
```

Beans:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.kafka.requestreply.ReplyingKafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class SpringMessageChannelsConfig {


    private ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "sudo-topic-listener.group");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }


    @Bean
    public MessageChannel toSuccessChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel toFailureChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSuccessChannel")
    public void handleSuccessMessages(Message<?> message) {
        log.info("**************Success************************");
        log.info("Header: {}", message.getPayload());
        log.info("Payload: {}", message.getPayload());
        log.info("*********************************************");
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toFailureChannel")
    public void handleFailureMessages(Message<?> message) {
        log.error("**************Failure************************");
        log.error("Header: {}", message.getPayload());
        log.error("Payload: {}", message.getPayload());
        log.error("*********************************************");
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory() {
        final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> replyingKafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, String> pf,
                                                                        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory) {
//        List<String> replies = List.of(KafkaConfig.KAFKA_INPUT_TOPIC, KafkaConfig.KAFKA_TRANSFORM_TOPIC, KafkaConfig.KAFKA_OUTPUT_TOPIC, "replies");
        List<String> replies = List.of(KafkaConfig.KAFKA_OUTPUT_TOPIC);
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> replyContainer =
                factory.createContainer(replies.toArray(new String[]{}));
//        replyContainer.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("kafka-out.replies");
        ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> template = new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, replyContainer);
        return template;
    }


}
```

I am unable to receve response from kafka-out
Message is present in in kafka-out
[image]

Logs

```
2023-06-03T22:12:25.572+05:30  INFO 55030 --- [anNameSet-0-C-1] i.s.s.config.KafkaConfig                 : *****************transformer*******************
2023-06-03T22:12:25.572+05:30  INFO 55030 --- [anNameSet-0-C-1] i.s.s.config.KafkaConfig                 : header: {kafka_offset=5, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@1f2a77ca, kafka_correlationId=30df0e54-fcf8-4a15-9b5b-75c47b21d480, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_replyTopic=kafka-out, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=kafka-in, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1685810545536, kafka_groupId=in-grp}
2023-06-03T22:12:25.573+05:30  INFO 55030 --- [anNameSet-0-C-1] i.s.s.config.KafkaConfig                 : payload: Hello: 2023-06-03T22:12:25.502159173
2023-06-03T22:12:25.573+05:30  INFO 55030 --- [anNameSet-0-C-1] i.s.s.config.KafkaConfig                 : *****************transformer*******************
2023-06-03T22:12:25.574+05:30  INFO 55030 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition kafka-transform-0 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to Hvc1mH6QSj2yL8WHi8VPfQ
2023-06-03T22:12:25.582+05:30  INFO 55030 --- [anNameSet-0-C-1] i.s.s.config.KafkaConfig                 : *****************output*******************
2023-06-03T22:12:25.582+05:30  INFO 55030 --- [anNameSet-0-C-1] i.s.s.config.KafkaConfig                 : header: {kafka_offset=5, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@56f1ea2e, kafka_correlationId=30df0e54-fcf8-4a15-9b5b-75c47b21d480, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_replyTopic=kafka-out, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=kafka-transform, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1685810545577, kafka_groupId=transform-grp}
2023-06-03T22:12:25.582+05:30  INFO 55030 --- [anNameSet-0-C-1] i.s.s.config.KafkaConfig                 : payload: Hello: 2023-06-03T22:12:25.502159173     => transformed!
2023-06-03T22:12:25.582+05:30  INFO 55030 --- [anNameSet-0-C-1] i.s.s.config.KafkaConfig                 : *****************output*******************
2023-06-03T22:12:25.584+05:30  INFO 55030 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition kafka-out-0 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to d83XhLq1THKtqAm3ycle0Q
2023-06-03T22:12:25.590+05:30 ERROR 55030 --- [anNameSet-0-C-1] o.s.k.r.ReplyingKafkaTemplate            : No pending reply: kafka-out-0@5 with correlationId: 33306466306535342d666366382d346131352d396235622d373563343762323164343830, perhaps timed out, or using a shared reply topic
2023-06-03T22:12:25.603+05:30  INFO 55030 --- [anNameSet-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-out-grp-4, groupId=out-grp] Seeking to offset 5 for partition kafka-out-0
2023-06-03T22:12:25.603+05:30 ERROR 55030 --- [anNameSet-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Error handler threw an exception

org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Seek to current after exception
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:208) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler.handleRemaining(DefaultErrorHandler.java:174) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2955) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.lambda$doInvokeRecordListener$58(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2833) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:562) ~[micrometer-observation-1.10.6.jar:1.10.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2820) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2672) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2558) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2200) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1555) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1519) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1394) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2992) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2933) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2899) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.lambda$doInvokeRecordListener$58(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2822) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
```

When I try to use OutboundGateway from [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/kafka.html#kafka-outbound-gateway) I keep getting following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValidationException: The MessageHandler [outGateway] can not be populated because of ambiguity with annotation attributes [sendTimeout, outputChannel, requiresReply] which are not allowed when an integration annotation is used with a @Bean definition for a MessageHandler.
The attribute causing the ambiguity is: [outputChannel].
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MessageChannel` has to sides: publisher and consumer.
Apparently your `kafkaOutput` channel comes without a subscriber.
And that's exactly an error you got.

So, what is your logic around that `kafkaOutput`? How are you expecting to handle a sent message to this one?

Are you thinking about getting a reply back to that `Message<?> sendToKafka()` gateway's method? Then it still not going to work without a subscriber to that `kafkaOutput`. It is really not a channel responsibility to make a sophisticated routing logic based on headers. You have to subscribe to the channel, consume message and then there you can make that reply routing logic. Likely there is a `@BridgeTo` which is able to apply a `BridgeHanler` on a message channel bean definition and really use a `replyChannel` header to bring it back to that gateway method call.

But that's not enough: with all that Kafka stuff in between you are introducing a network jumps and (de)serialization aspect to the data you transfer over that network to the broker and back. The mentioned `replyChannel` header, populated by the gateway call, is an instance of a `TemporaryReplyChannel` which is not serializable since it is tied to s specific waiting thread in the current JVM.
Therefore your logic is a bit wrong since reply cannot come back to after those Kafka-backed channels. However the framework provides for us some special hook - `HeaderChannelRegistry` and `headerChannelsToString`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-transformation.html#header-channel-registry. Either way this is still not robust since you may have several instances of your application and the message sent to your Kafka-backed channels might be received in other instance where that local `HeaderChannelRegistry` does not have a entry for `TemporaryReplyChannel` to map from its string representation from headers.

I would really recommend to look into a `KafkaProducerMessageHandler` with a gateway mode.

The right configuration is like this:

```
        @Bean
        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "kafkaRequests")
        public KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, String> outGateway(
                ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
            
            KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, String> producerMessageHandler = 
                    new KafkaProducerMessageHandler<>(kafkaTemplate);
            producerMessageHandler.setOutputChannelName("kafkaReplies");
            return producerMessageHandler;
        }
```

That sample in the doc comes with an error. Please, raise a GH issue to fix it.
Thanks.

Comment: Also, sending to a channel is a one-way operation (send only); you should not be using a "replying" template there; the sending thread will block waiting for a reply that will never come (and time out).

Comment: Thanks for correcting the approach, I will do other operation on intermediate channels and follow back response on  Kafka output, let me try that. https://gitlab.com/silentsudo/spring-integrations/-/tree/feat/kafak-backed-channels-gateway-fail-2